# Android DatabaseHandler: deleting a row

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm building an internal database in my Android application.
I use it to manage a shopping cart, so i need to delete, add and update rows
Java code:

```
public class DatabaseCarrello extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "biosfera_carrello";
private static final String TABLE_SESSION = "sessione";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_ID_PROD = "id_prodotto";
private static final String KEY_ID_USER = "id_user";
private static final String KEY_NOME_PROD = "nome_prodotto";
private static final String KEY_COSTO = "costo";
private static final String KEY_QUANTITA = "quantita";

public DatabaseCarrello(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_SESSION + "(" + 
          KEY_ID_PROD
          + " text not null, "+
          KEY_ID_USER
          +" text not null, "+
          KEY_NOME_PROD
          +" text not null, "+
          KEY_COSTO
          +" text not null, "+
          KEY_QUANTITA
          +" text not null "+
          " );";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SESSION);
    onCreate(db);

}

public Carrello getCarrello(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SESSION,new String[] { KEY_ID_PROD, KEY_ID_USER,KEY_NOME_PROD,KEY_COSTO,KEY_QUANTITA }, KEY_ID + "=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
     Carrello carrello = new Carrello(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5));
 return carrello;
}

public int updateQuantita(Carrello stato) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUANTITA, stato.getQuantita());
    return db.update(TABLE_SESSION, values, KEY_ID_PROD + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(stato.getIDprodotto()) });

}
public void addProdotto(Carrello prodotto){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID_PROD, prodotto.getIDprodotto());
    values.put(KEY_ID_USER, prodotto.getIDuser());
    values.put(KEY_NOME_PROD, prodotto.getNomeProdotto());
    values.put(KEY_QUANTITA, prodotto.getQuantita());
    values.put(KEY_COSTO, prodotto.getCosto());
    db.insert(TABLE_SESSION, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public List<Carrello> getAllCarrello(){
    List<Carrello> carrello = new ArrayList<Carrello>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SESSION;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Carrello contact = new Carrello();
            contact.setIDuser(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setIDprodotto(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setQuantita(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setCosto(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setNomeProdotto(cursor.getString(5));
            carrello.add(contact);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return carrello;
}

public void deleteAllCarrello(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_SESSION, null, null);
    db.close();

}

public void deleteProdottoCarrello(Carrello carrello) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_SESSION, KEY_ID_PROD + " = ?",
            new String[] {carrello.getIDprodotto() });
    db.close();
}}
```

If i want to delete a row, which datas i have to pass?
I tried so:

```
db.deleteProdottoCarrello(new Carrello(id_prodotto,null,null,null,null));
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Could you post your logcat trace?

Comment: LogCat says nothing ... there's no error or something like that. It seems that nothing happens

Comment: try put `db.delete(TABLE_SESSION, KEY_ID_PROD + " = ?",
            new String[] {carrello.getIDprodotto() });` this line into try catch block and see what happens. Dont forget to print your exception in catch block

Comment: I tried, but nothing. No Exception message anywhere ... 
I'm groping in the dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//public void deleteProdottoCarrello(Carrello carrello) {
  //  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  //  int i = carrello.getIDprodotto();
   // System.out.println(i);
  //  db.delete(TABLE_SESSION, KEY_ID_PROD + " = ?",
  //          new String[] { i });
  //  db.close();
//}}
```

change you `DATABASE_CREATE` string to like following.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_SESSION + " (" + 
      KEY_ID_PROD
      + " text not null, "+
      KEY_ID_USER
      +" text not null, "+
      KEY_NOME_PROD
      +" text not null, "+
      KEY_COSTO
      +" text not null, "+
      KEY_QUANTITA
      +" text not null "+
      " );";
```

Note space between tablename and openbrace. `TABLE_SESSION + " (" +` here.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i tried so:
`public void deleteProdottoCarrello(String i) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("ID",i);
        db.delete(TABLE_SESSION, KEY_ID_PROD + " = ?",
                new String[] { i });
        db.close();
    }`
and
`db.deleteProdottoCarrello(String.valueOf(v.getId()));`
It's not working yet. The value of `i` is correct ... Does exist a way to print the query?

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine Check it now.